# I need to read x and y values from .txt file in C

Tags: c, file, text

I need to read x and y coordinates from a text file then use them for polynomial regression. I can do the regression part but I can't read the values from the file. Data points are

5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50

17,24,31,33,37,37,40,40,42,41

First row is x and second row is y, and they're exactly written like this in the txt file.

From another question I managed to read all the numbers into a single x array of 20 but I really need for them in seperate arrays as x and y. How can I do this?
Here's my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *data;
data = fopen("data.txt", "r");

int x[20];
int i=0;


for(i=0; i<20; i++)
    fscanf(data, "%d,", &x[i]);


for(i=0; i<20; i++)
printf("x are: %d\n", x[i]);


fclose(data);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a similar loop with another array: `int y[20]; for(i=0; i<20; i++) fscanf(data, "%d,", &y[i]);`? You also need to think what happens if there are fewer or more numbers in each line and add error checking etc.

Comment: is it always 10 elements in each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have 10 int in one line and 10 more int in another line as you stated in your question, you can use one more array `int y[10];` to store `y` values. And use two `for` loops - one for reading 10 x values, and another for reading 10 y values. And both your arrays just need to store only `10` elements.

```
    int x[10];
    int y[10];  // Array to store y values
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++) // Read first 10 values to x array
            fscanf(data, "%d,", &x[i]);

    for(i=0; i<10; i++) // Read next 10 values to y array
            fscanf(data, "%d,", &y[i]);

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
            printf("x are: %d\n", x[i]);

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
            printf("y are: %d\n", y[i]);
```

However if there is a chance that there may be different number of integers  - more or less than 10 - in those lines then you will need to do more checks.

Answer (score 0):

check exist the comma

```
int x[20], y[20];
int i, n;
char tail;

for(i = 0; i < 20 && 2 == fscanf(data, "%d%c", &x[i], &tail); i++){
    if(tail != ',')
        break;
}
n = i+1;//if(n > 20){ puts("bad format!"); return -1;}

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    fscanf(data, "%d,", &y[i]);

fclose(data);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", x[i], y[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all i advice you to write your `x` and `y` values by pairs (seems more logical, so it is simpler to implement). For example:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

So `fscanf(FILE* fp, char* format,...)` :

- `FILE* fp` - pointer to stream you want to  read data from (which can be even standard `stdin` which makes `fscanf()` work as `scanf()`);
- `char* format` - format string (for example: `"%d%s%d"`);
- `...` -  addresses of variables and / or areas in memory that will receive inputted data. Number of variables are specified by `char* format`.

You use `fscanf(data, "%d,", &x[i]);` instead of using `fscanf(data, "%d%d", &x[i],&y[i]);` forgetting that you get as much data as you specify in `char* format`.

Also note, that `fscanf()` as well as `scanf()` returns number of successfully inputted data, meaning that you can do something like this:

```
while(fscanf(data,"%d%d",&x[i],&y[i]) == 2) {
    // do something, or don't
}
```

You can leave `while` empty. In the end, you will get your `x` and `y` points stored in separate arrays. What happens is that `fscanf()` tries to read two integer values. if he manages to do this, he returns number of successfully inputted data, meaning 2. Else he returns 1 (if you missed `x` or `y` in pair) or 0 (if it is end of file).